# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component when submitting login form

Tags: node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, use-effect, unmount

I have a navbar that contains a login form.

The identification is by username, password and ID.

If the user is already connected to the system, a logout form will appear.

The check whether the user is connected or not, is done with userContext.

I have the "submitHandler" function that does fetch to DB A, to see if the user is even registered in the system.

Then I have the "getUserType" function that does fetch to DB B, to see what the user's type is.

(I do not have the option to combine the 2 fetch into one call, that will return both whether the user is registered, and also what his type is ...)

At the first click of the submit button - everything works fine. I can see the spinner and get an error message if I entered incorrect data.

If I click the submit button again, according to the debugger, the first fetch call, returns the error: **"Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function."**

And also my whole screen is erased and I only see a white screen.

What am I doing wrong?
How to fix it?
Is it related to useEffect?

I'll be glad to receive your help.
Thanks!

```
const Test = (props) => {
  const [userLoginDetails, setUserLoginDetails] = useState({
    userName: "",
    userPassword: "",
    userID: "",
  });

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isLogIn, setIsLogin] = useState(false);
  const [isCompanyMember, setIsCompanyMember] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const userContext = useContext(UserContext);
  const userAuth = userContext.authed;

  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    let updatedState = { ...userLoginDetails };
    updatedState[name] = value;
    setUserLoginDetails(updatedState);
  };

  const getUserType = async () => {
    const bodyContent = {
      userName: userLoginDetails.userName,
    };
    const response = await fetch(`${URL}/members/${userLoginDetails.userID}`, {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(bodyContent),
      credentials: "include",
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      setError(true);
      setIsLoading(false);
      setMessage("something went wrong! try again!");
      return;
    }
    const body = await response.json();
    userContext.handleChange(body.data.result, true, userLoginDetails.userName);
    setIsLogin(true);
    setError(false);
    setIsLoading(false);
    setMessage("");
  };

  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(false);
    fetch(`someURL`, {
      method: "post",
      json: true,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        UserName: userLoginDetails.userName,
        PassWord: userLoginDetails.userPassword,
        Id: userLoginDetails.userID,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((response) => {
        //The combination of user, id and password is correct!
        if (response) {
          setIsCompanyMember(true);
        } else {
          //The combination of user, id and password is wrong!
          setError(true);
          setIsLoading(false);
          setMessage("combination of user,id an password didnt work!");
        }
      })
      //unexpected problem...
      .catch(() => {
        setError(true);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setMessage("connection problem");
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${URL}/login/`, { credentials: "include" })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.data.loggedIn === true) {
          setIsLogin(true);
          setError(false);
          setMessage("");
          userContext.handleChange(
            response.data.userType,
            true,
            response.data.userName
          );
        }
      })
      .catch();
    return () => {
      //for cleanup
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isCompanyMember) {
      getUserType();
    }
  }, [isCompanyMember]);
  return (
    <nav>
      {/* An alert message */}
      {!isLogIn && error && (
        <div role="alert" style={{ margin: "auto" }}>
          {message}
          <button
            type="button"
            className="close"
            data-dismiss="alert"
            aria-label="Close"
          >
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
      {/* login and logout forms */}
      <ul>
        <li>
          {isLoading && <TinySpinner />}

          {!userAuth && (
            <form id={classes.login} onSubmit={submitHandler}>
              <div>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="userName"
                  id={classes.login_username}
                  placeholder="Username"
                  autoComplete="username"
                  onChange={onChangeHandler}
                  value={userLoginDetails.userName}
                ></input>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  name="userPassword"
                  id={classes.login_password}
                  placeholder="Password"
                  autoComplete="current-password"
                  onChange={onChangeHandler}
                  value={userLoginDetails.userPassword}
                ></input>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="userID"
                  id={classes.login_userid}
                  placeholder="ID"
                  autoComplete="id"
                  onChange={onChangeHandler}
                  value={userLoginDetails.userID}
                ></input>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Log in"></input>
              </div>
            </form>
          )}
          {/* TODO: logout form */}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
export default Test;
```

Comment: Can you change the code example to be minimal and still have this problem?

Comment: Which fetch fail? The fetch inside submitHandler or inside useeffect?

Comment: @shanif The fetch inside the submitHandler was failed in the second time I clicked it. The same scenario(I inserted the same details, worng details indeed) but in the second time I didn't see the spinner and the message error. Just the exception...